# Could someone explain how I can replace objects in column 1 from one table with an object from column 2 of another table within Pandas?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCieI.jpg

(Currently using Juptyer Notebook for Python and implementing Pandas for Data Analysis)

As shown in the images above, I have two tables from two different csv files. The first table is the masterList which holds the Symbols on the left side and on the right are the corresponding ID of another database (Ensembl). The Second table below is the refList where I need to covert each column (both are symbol IDs) to Ensembl using the masterList.

I looked at Pands's replace function and tried it but it replaces ints and strings if you add masterList.str.replace[]. But I recently learned my values are type: object so it won't let me use the replace properly.

So I am currently stuck on this and would love advice from any Pandas veterans.

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not post a screenshot of your code. Share it here using for instance: `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` or `print(df)`

Comment: I apologize, I'm relatively new to posting on stack overflow and have not yet fully grasped the proper posting syntax rules! Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: No worries. But take a look on other questions around here on SO. Screenshots is a big no-no.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary and then replace:

```
mapping = dict(df1[['Gene Symbol', 'Ensembl']].values)
df2 = df2.replace(mapping)
```

Full Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': list('abc'),
    'B': ['val1','val2','val3']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'C': list('abc'),
    'D': list('ccd')
})

mapping = dict(df1[['A', 'B']].values)
#mapping = df1.set_index('A')['B']  # alternative

df2.replace(mapping, inplace=True)

print(df2)
```

Returns:

```
      C     D
0  val1  val3
1  val2  val3
2  val3     d
```

Comment: The way you come up with `mapping` is interesting. Normally I'd say: `mapping = df1.set_index('A')['B']` is the most used approach. If this answers OP's question, I'll upvote.

Comment: Anton, what do the parameters ('A')['B'] mean in .set_index?

Comment: @AlbertTanjaya the first `'A'` is the parameter you are sending in to the `set_index()` function. This makes the `A` column the index of the dataframe. Now: the `['B']` part selects the `B` column (which in this case is the only one left) and returns a series. A pandas series is basically a vector, but it can also have an index in which this case it becomes a map. Try printing the different steps. For instance `print(df1.set_index('A'))` and `print(df1.set_index('A')['B'])` to see the difference.